# How to use a reserved external IP address from Shared VPC host project in a service project's GKE LoadBalancer service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I've found two references ([here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/networklb-backend-service#xpn-architecture) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#ip_addresses)) in the GCP docs saying that I may reserve an IPv4 address in the host project and use it in the service project.

My case is that I have a host project where I have a Shared VPC network and I've reserved an external IP address there. Now I would like to assigned this IPv4 address to a GKE LoadBalancer service as described [in here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service-load-balancer-parameters#spd-static-ip), ie. I want to type it in the `spec.loadBalancerIP` field in [k8s Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

I'm positive that the Shared VPC is somewhat properly configured as I have two clusters (one in the host project and one in the service project) running and I'm able to query podA@host-k8s-cluster from podB@service-k8s-cluster, but as for the k8s Service with `type: LoadBalancer` in the service project, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer requested ip "..." is neither static nor assigned to the LB
```

**How do I properly use/share this ext. IPv4 address to the service project's k8s LoadBalancer Service?**

As a side note, the docs also mention that all the GCP load-balancer services must be defined within the same (ie. service) project as the cluster, which happens automatically if the IPv4 address is also in the same project, but I can't see any of these resources being created in the service project if I specify ext IPv4 address from the host project.

---

*quotes from the docs*

> A **regional external IP address must be defined in either** the same project as the load balancer **or the Shared VPC host project**.

> Static external IPv4 addresses: External IPv4 address objects defined in the host project **can be used by resources in either** that host project **or any attached service project**.